# How to add JSON string to the array in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have retrieve JSON from my controller of asp.net mvc :

```
{"ja":
[
{"Name":"ABC1","PictureName1":"my image name1","ID":1},   
{"Name":"ABC2","PictureName2":"my image name2","ID":2},
.......
]}
```

In my view, I create one array in jquery :

```
var list_lastpage = [];
```

And I want to push all the element of my JSON to my new array that I just creat.

Could anyone tell me, how can I push and display the JSON(ja) to the array (list_lastpage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to push all items in the `ja` array into the list_lastpage, try the following:

```
for (var i = 0, length = ja.length; i < length; i++) {
  list_lastpage.push(ja[i]);
}
```

**Update**

I'm unsure how you want the array to be displayed, but perhaps the following can help:

```
$.each(list_lastpage, function(i, val) {
  var div = $('<div></div>');
  div.attr('id', val.ID);
  div.attr('name', val.Name);
  div.val(val.PictureName);
  $('#containerId').append(div);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and could you tell me how to display this array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `success` handler of your AJAX request:

```
success: function(json) {
    list_lastpage.push(json.ja);
}
```

If you have multiple `ja` objects in your returned JSON, try this:

```
success: function(json) {
    $.each(json.ja, function(i, val) {
        list_lastpage.push(val);
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe he is looking for merging `[]` with array from `ja`? Simple `push` will add new array to `list_lastpage`.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks - now I re-read the OP that does seem more like what he's trying to do.

Comment: Thank Rory McCrossan, and could you tell me how to display the array?

Answer (score 1):

In the success of your Ajax call, loop through the Json string and add to the array:

```
        success: function (ja) {
            $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(ja), function () {
                list_lastpage.push(this);
            });
```

Comment: If you expect `json` from server, there is no need in parsing the incoming data. JQuery does that job for you.

Answer (score 1):

apart from the other answers if you want to display the array in your view you can try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/userid", function (data) {
        var items = [];


        $.each(data, function (key, users) {
            items.push('<li id="' + users.UserId + '">' + users.UserName + '</li>');
        });

                $('<ul/>', {
                    'class': 'Users-list',
                    html: items.join('')
                }).appendTo('p');
           });
   });
 <p></p>
```